# TypeError: shooter is not iterable when trying to sort tbody ascending in react js

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, sorting

I render tbody with:`

```
renderIndivPoints = () => {
  
     return this.state.shooter.map(
       (player, id) =>{
        return (<tr key={id}>
          <td>{player.id}</td>
          <td>{player.number}</td>
          <td>{player.points}</td>
        </tr>)
      })
    }`
```

Now I want to sort my tbody ascending on column player.number

with google's help I came up with the code:

```
renderIndivPoints = () => {
      const shooter = this.state

      let sortedShooter = [...shooter]
      sortedShooter.sort((a,b) => {
        if (a.number - b.number) {
          return -1
        }
        if (b.number - a.number) {
          return 1
        }
        return 0

      })
     return this.state.shooter.map(
       (player, id) =>{
        return (<tr key={id}>
          <td>{player.id}</td>
          <td>{player.number}</td>
          <td>{player.points}</td>
        </tr>)
      })
    }
```

Unfortunately, the above code is causing "TypeError: shooter is not iterable"
Would be grateful for your help in solving this problem.

Thanks in advance
Peter

Comment: Your const shooter assignment is wrong, you're assigning the whole `this.state` to shooter. So either assign it with `const shooter = this.state.shooter` or destructure it from the state like `const {shooter} = this.state`

Comment: thanks davbuc :) Now I don´t get error, but do not sort the tbody either

Comment: you're welcome, and now the problem is that you're not iterating over the sortedShooters instead you're using the state.shooters. Change `this.state.shooter.map` to `sortedShooter.map` in your return statement.

Comment: Doing so, I get "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"

Comment: Then create a working example of it in a https://codesandbox.io/ please as nobody can guess what youre doing now :D

Comment: First time I use codesandbox, hopefully i did it the right way https://codesandbox.io/s/indiv-points-h1o2l?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Well the type error only occurs while using Typescript which isnt the case in your codesandbox

Comment: I was not aware that I was using Typescript. I blame Video Studio Code for that...

Comment: so its working now right?